# Proving the map $\Psi: \mathcal{V}_pM\to T_pM$ defined by $\Psi[\gamma] = \gamma'(0)$ is well defined and bijective.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

I am reading Professor Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds book and one of the problems asks the following. How would you approach a proof to this? Also do I need to prove it is well defined? Or is that just a byproduct? Thank you for your time and help!

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary and $p\in M.$ Let $\mathcal{V}_pM$ denote the set of equivalence classes of smooth curves starting at $p$ under the relation $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2$ if $(f\circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (f\circ \gamma_2)'(0)$ for every smooth real-valued function $f$ defined in a neighborhood of $p.$ Show that the map $\Psi: \mathcal{V}_pM\to T_pM$ defined by $\Psi[\gamma] = \gamma'(0)$ is well defined and bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm proving it for $p$ in the interior, other case is similar. Pick a suitable chart, such that write $\gamma = (x_1(t), \cdots, x_n(t))$ with $\gamma(0) = O$. Then by chain rule, $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_O x_i'(0)$. So just set $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = x_i$ for all $i$ to conclude if $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2$, then $\gamma_1'(0) = \gamma_2'(0)$. This show the map is well defined.

It's bijective, because for any $v \in T_pM$, just pick a straight line parametrizing it (ie, identify $T_O(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, and define $\gamma(t) = tv$) and consider it's class, this gives an well defined inverse (check it).

Comment: Note that we can show $\Psi$ is well-defined (and injectivive) without using coordinates, since $\gamma_1'(0) = \gamma'_2(0)  \iff \gamma'_1(0)f = \gamma'_2(0)f \iff (f \circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (f \circ \gamma_2)'(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the proof and help, Lelouch and Si Kucing!